# Error in query ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a query that worked for me when I was using Mysql.
Now I get this error on Oracle :

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT o.neNesId, COUNT(o) 
FROM ParNe AS o 
WHERE o.neBanId = :neBanId 
GROUP BY o.neNesId
```

Any ideas why I have this error?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is:

```
SELECT o.neNesId, COUNT(o)
FROM ParNe AS o
WHERE o.neBanId = :neBanId
GROUP BY o.neNesId
```

My guess is that `o.o` is not a valid field.  So, you have a table name where a column name is expected.
Try this instead:

```
SELECT o.neNesId, COUNT(*)
FROM ParNe AS o
WHERE o.neBanId = :neBanId
GROUP BY o.neNesId
```

Or replace the `*` with a valid column name.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn' work neither with * nor with a valid column name .thanks

Comment: @Amine . . . Are you sure the `group by` is getting processed?  That type of error might occur if you have a column in the `select` that is not in the `group by`.

Comment: it was working when i used Mysql Now when i changed my DB to oracle i get this error .

Answer (score 0):

use count(*) . count(o) is used in hibernate not in sql query

Comment: use count(*) it  will help you

Comment: i try it but unfortunately doesn't work .thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to select count(*) or count(1) as in Gordon's example. If you insist on using your query syntax, which is not necessary at all then try this:

```
SELECT neNesId, count(o) AS o_cnt
  FROM
  (  -- your query here --
   SELECT 1 neNesId, 2 AS o FROM dual
  )
  GROUP BY neNesId
  /
```